# Restarting activity inside onClick method

Tags: android, android-activity, restart

I have an app which reads .txt file and displays contents in table layout.

here is my MainActivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new TableLayout(this,0));
    }    
}
```

Inside TableLayout class when adding first row (headers), i also add on click listeners.

Here is the code that gets executed when click happens:

```
public class MyOnClickListener extends MainActivity implements OnClickListener {

    int rowNumber;
    public MyOnClickListener(int rowNumber) {
        this.rowNumber = rowNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(new TableLayout(context,rowNumber));         
    }
};
```

context is saved from when activity is first started, but i get nullpointexception error with this as an argument.
What i would like to do when header is clicked is to recreate table with header number argument.
So my question is what should i do to restart table creation within onClick method?

Edit: this is how context is saved

```
Context context;

public TableLayout(Context context, int rowNr) {

    super(context);

    this.context = context;
```

Comment: Show how you initialize context... Furthermore: your MyOnClickListener has a constructor, but it's an activity, so you're not going to call that

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I did it this way to pass in parameters. And it extends MainActivity so setContentView() can be called. Do you suggest another way?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new TableLayout(this, getRowNumber()));
    }

    protected int getRowNumber(){
        return 0;
    }    
}
```

and then you do something like

```
public class MyOnClickListener extends MainActivity implements OnClickListener {

    // here you initialize rowNumber
    static int rowNumber = 0;

    @Override
    protected void getRowNumber(){
        return rowNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // here you set your rowNumber
        rowNumber = some_value;
        recreate();         
    }
};
```

P.S: I haven't compiled this but you can get the idea

Comment: (1) Why does the `MyOnClickListener extends MainActivity`? That seems unnecessary. (2) The OP's question is phrased a bit weirdly... but after reading his entire question it doesnt seem like he wants to restart the entire activity... the OP just wants to reset a specific part of the activity layout. So using `recreate()` is almost certainly not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: (1) I extended `MainActivity` because that's what he used and may be his application requires that so i didn't change this (2) in his `onClick` he's using `setcontentview()`which means he's not looking to just a part of the layout but all the layout.. if he was looking to change some part of the layout, i would suggest using a **Fragment**

Comment: How about `class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener`?

Comment: yeah that could work too.. but since I don't know what he has in all the activities.. i didn't want to change the way he' organizing his activities.. may be activities that extend `MainActivity` have different behaviors and some others they share from `MainActivity`

Comment: He only mentioned one activity in his question.

Comment: and that's why we can't be sure why he did that (but you're right I  would be very surprised if he's extending `MainActivity` for no reason)

Comment: Hi...thanks for help, I will try to implement your code and report back. I am extending MainActivity because of setcontentview() method...i'm fairly new to android development, so i don't know if this is even ok. What i am trying to do is to recreate table with column parameter, so the table is sorted by that column - by clicking column header. My idea was to create table again from scratch, but if someone knows there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Hi, i tried your code...but it does not work. I changed min sdk version to 11 because of recreate() method, but i get an error at that line (nullPointerException). I also tried to run it with just recreate() method on click, but it's the same.